# How do I open a filtered port in pf?

Tags: firewall

I have opened a number of ports, and am familiar enough with `pfctl`, but even though I have opened various ports, then show up as "filtered" - which means of course that they are not open.

How can I open them, or is it a function of having a suitable app using them?
For example

```
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 53
```

In a scan this shows up as

> 53 dns Filtered

How can I open this port?

Answer (score 1):

Usually port scanners use UDP and TCP to scan port. Since most implementations of DNS servers use UDP you probably also have to open 53/udp:

```
pass in proto udp from any to any port 53
```

Comment: PORT   STATE         SERVICE
53/udp open|filtered domain
53/tcp Filtered

Comment: the command above in pf.conf just opens the UDP port, doesn't change the "filtered" flag for tcp